# What is the expected behavior of removing the is="" attribute from Custom Element?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, custom-element

For example,

suppose we have `<div is="awesomebutton"></div>` and a Custom Element definition:

```
document.registerElement('awesomebutton', AwesomeButton)
```

What is the expected behavior when the `is=""` attribute is removed or replaced with a new value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Per section 7 of the latest Working Draft specification (26 February 2016)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-custom-elements-20160226/#instantiating-custom-elements), it should have no effect on the type of the element:

> After a custom element is instantiated, changing the value of the `is` attribute **must not** affect this element's custom element type.

However the `attributeChangedCallback` should still be triggered as normal. (The specification does not exempt the `is` attribute from triggering it.) You can observe that behaviour here in a supporting browser (Chrome, or Firefox with the `dom.webcomponents.enabled` config flag set):

```js
'use strict';

const prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
prototype.attributeChangedCallback = function(name, oldValue, newValue) {
  this.textContent = `my "${name}" attribute changed to "${newValue}"!`; 
};

document.registerElement('examp-el', {prototype: prototype, extends: 'div'});

const el = document.createElement('div', 'examp-el');
el.textContent = "I'm an element!";

document.body.appendChild(el);
el.setAttribute('is', "changed once");
el.removeAttribute('is');
el.setAttribute('is', "changed twice");
el.setAttribute('is', "changed thrice");
```

This specification is not yet standardized and significant changes are coming soon, but I don't expect this behaviour to change. It's still specified by [Section 2.3 of the latest version of the Editor's Draft (currently 17 March 2016)](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-elements-core-concepts):

> After a custom element is created, changing the value of the `is` attribute does not change the element's behavior.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Marking as the answer once the new-question timer expires. Do you know what is meant by "If both types of custom element types are provided at the time of element's instantiation, the custom tag must win over the type extension" in the spec?

Comment: @trusktr I believe that's meant to clarify that you're not allowed to do `<one-custom-type is="another-custom-type"></one-custom-type>` (you're only allowed to extend built-in types like that), and that if you do, the browser is supposed to ignore the `is` attribute and only use the tag name (`one-custom-type`).

Comment: It seems like DOM cloning will probably respect the new value of `is`, rather than using the prototype from the old one, but I might wait until that section of the spec is a bit more nailed down before adding it to the post.